# Silverlight binding not updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, data-binding

I am having a problem with my binding that has me stumped. Whenever I set my Building property the first time, my Title `RasedText` object's text is set to what I am expecting. However, when I set a new value to the Building property, the Title object's text field still remains the old value. Got any ideas why?

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty buildingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
(
    "building",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(FloorPlan),
    new PropertyMetadata((d,e) => 
        {
            try
            {
                (d as FloorPlan).BuildingChanged();
            } catch {}
        }
));

public string Building
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(buildingProperty); }
    set { SetValue(buildingProperty, value); }
}

private void ChildWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Code...

    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.Source = Building;
    binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    Title.SetBinding(TextControls.RaisedText.TextProperty, binding);

    //Code...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not set the property `Building` as the source of a binding. Instead you would use as source the instance of class `FloorPlan` that you want to bind to (`this` here) and also specify the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) property:

```
Binding binding = new Binding(); 
binding.Source = this;
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Building"); 
// no need for the following, since it is the default
// binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay; 
Title.SetBinding(TextControls.RaisedText.TextProperty, binding);
```

This will also only work if you adhere to the property naming conventions and declare `Building` with an appropriate name that starts with a uppercase character:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty buildingProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Building", typeof(string), typeof(FloorPlan), ...);
```

And it would also be standard to declare it like this, since it is a public class member:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BuildingProperty = ...
```